# Bug İ am getting error "unity 2022.1.23f1_9636b062134a"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am constantly getting the error "Unity 2022.1.23f1_9636b062134a" and unity shuts down. how can i solve this?

[image: 1]

I couldn't try anything because I couldn't find the cause of the error.

Comment: Perhaps your unity editor version is not up to date?

Comment: See the error and crash logs in `%AppData%/Local/Unity/Editor` ... also stick to the latest LTS Unity version which is currently `2021.3.X`

Comment: Any chance your code goes into a loop it cant break out of?

Answer (score 0):

remove the script folder and try to open the project if it does open, then add script by script when it crashes you'll know where is the issue (this applies to files other than scripts)

Answer (score -1):

I too have had the same problem. Have you ever tried resetting Windows?

Comment: yes, but the problem is not solved.

Comment: It may be a problem with the version itself. How about using a different version?

Comment: It could be a problem with the computer part.

Comment: @gdsafgd - something like this should be a comment rather than an answer.